# Should [iisversion] questions be retagged [iis-version]?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I got my tag synonym request the wrong way round. I wanted to suggest that [[iis-7.5]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iis-7.5/info) become a synonym for [[iis7.5]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iis7.5/info) with [iis7.5] being the master tag.

However, upon reviewing the existing IIS tags and comparing them to technology tags that have a version suffix (for example, [[asp.net-1.1]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-1.1/info), [[asp.net-2.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-2.0/info), [[asp.net-mvc-2]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc-2/info)), perhaps we should re-tag [all](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iis5/info) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iis6/info) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iis7/info) [iisversion] questions to [iis-version] to be more consistent with the convention adopted for other technology tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synonym you suggested has now been [voted in](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iis-7.5/synonyms), and preferring hyphenated version numbers seems to work better for most tags.

It makes sense to rename [iis5] to [iis-5] (123 questions) and the same for 6 (×1,070) and 7 (×1,785), but, for now, as long as just one tag is used for each version, they can always be renamed later.

Comment: Thanks Gnome....hopefully one of the mods will turn their attention to this retag.